# Unable to correctly get the output of Custom Model Tflite Model in Android application

Tags: python, android, neural-network, tensorflow-lite, firebase-mlkit

I have trained a very simple model and converted it into a Tflite model as well....the python code for the model is as follows

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sat Sep 28 21:05:22 2019

@author: Aneshka Goyal
"""

import tensorflow as tf
def freeze_session(session, keep_var_names=None, output_names=None, clear_devices=True):
    """
    Freezes the state of a session into a pruned computation graph.

    Creates a new computation graph where variable nodes are replaced by
    constants taking their current value in the session. The new graph will be
    pruned so subgraphs that are not necessary to compute the requested
    outputs are removed.
    @param session The TensorFlow session to be frozen.
    @param keep_var_names A list of variable names that should not be frozen,
                          or None to freeze all the variables in the graph.
    @param output_names Names of the relevant graph outputs.
    @param clear_devices Remove the device directives from the graph for better portability.
    @return The frozen graph definition.
    """
    graph = session.graph
    with graph.as_default():
        freeze_var_names = list(set(v.op.name for v in tf.global_variables()).difference(keep_var_names or []))
        output_names = output_names or []
        output_names += [v.op.name for v in tf.global_variables()]
        input_graph_def = graph.as_graph_def()
        if clear_devices:
            for node in input_graph_def.node:
                node.device = ""
        frozen_graph = tf.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(
            session, input_graph_def, output_names, freeze_var_names)
        return frozen_graph

inp = tf.placeholder(name="inp", dtype=tf.float32, shape=(1, 1))

w = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1, 1], tf.float32), dtype=tf.float32, name="w")



y = tf.matmul(w, inp)



out = tf.identity(y, name="out")



init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()



with tf.Session() as sess:

    sess.run(init_op)



    # After Init var, change the value to 2

    assignment = w.assign([[2]])

    sess.run(assignment)



    output = sess.run(out, feed_dict={inp: [[1]]})

    print (output)



    frozen_graph = freeze_session(sess, output_names=[out.op.name])



    tflite_model = tf.contrib.lite.toco_convert(frozen_graph, [inp], [out])

    open("mat_mul.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

I am able to get the correct dimentions of the input and output of this model to put it into the following android code inorder to integrate with my android app but i doubt taking the output out correctly from the FirebaseInterpreter....as indicated by comment over the try-catch block.

```
    package com.example.aneshkagoyal.samplecustom;

    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
    import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
    import com.google.firebase.ml.common.FirebaseMLException;
    import com.google.firebase.ml.custom.FirebaseModelDataType;
    import com.google.firebase.ml.custom.FirebaseModelInputOutputOptions;
    import com.google.firebase.ml.custom.FirebaseModelInputs;
    import com.google.firebase.ml.custom.FirebaseModelInterpreter;
    import com.google.firebase.ml.custom.FirebaseModelManager;
    import com.google.firebase.ml.custom.FirebaseModelOptions;
    import com.google.firebase.ml.custom.FirebaseModelOutputs;
    import com.google.firebase.ml.custom.model.FirebaseLocalModelSource;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        FirebaseModelInterpreter firebaseInterpreter;
        FirebaseModelInputs inputs;
        FirebaseModelInputOutputOptions inputOutputOptions;
        TextView t;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            t = findViewById(R.id.my_text);
            FirebaseLocalModelSource localSource =
                    new FirebaseLocalModelSource.Builder("mat_mul")  // Assign a name to this model
                            .setAssetFilePath("mat_mul.tflite")
                            .build();
            FirebaseModelManager.getInstance().registerLocalModelSource(localSource);
            FirebaseModelOptions options = new FirebaseModelOptions.Builder()
                    .setLocalModelName("asset")
                    .build();
            try {
                 firebaseInterpreter =
                        FirebaseModelInterpreter.getInstance(options);
            } catch (FirebaseMLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }




            // Define the Input and Output dimensions and types

            try {
                 inputOutputOptions = new FirebaseModelInputOutputOptions.Builder()

                        .setInputFormat(0, FirebaseModelDataType.FLOAT32, new int[]{1,1})//This line

                        .setOutputFormat(0, FirebaseModelDataType.FLOAT32, new int[]{1,1})//This line

                        .build();
            } catch (FirebaseMLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            float[][] input;
            input = new float[1][1];
            //output = new float[1][1];
            input[0][0]= 21.0f;
            try {
                 inputs = new FirebaseModelInputs.Builder()
                        .add(input)  // add() as many input arrays as your model requires
                        .build();
            } catch (FirebaseMLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("Failure","in InputBuilder");
            }
//Check if the output is being correctly taken as float[1][1]
            try {
                firebaseInterpreter.run(inputs, inputOutputOptions)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(
                                new OnSuccessListener<FirebaseModelOutputs>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(FirebaseModelOutputs result) {
                                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"output"+result.<float[][]>getOutput(0).toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        Log.d("ANSWERIS", result.<float[][]>getOutput(0).toString());
                                        t.setText(result.<float[][]>getOutput(0).toString());
                                    }
                                })
                        .addOnFailureListener(
                                new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                        // Task failed with an exception
                                        // ...
                                        Log.d("Failure","ho gyaa");
                                    }
                                });
            } catch (FirebaseMLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }



    }
```

The output I get in the app is a garbage sort of value [[F@6061395 and the value changes every time and the output I get when I run the python script(only) is [[2.]] which should be the right answer. 
Please help by suggesting the probable sources of error as per my feeling it should be something with the dimensionality as i am not sure if i have done it right.

Comment: Did you try to open ```mat_mul.tflite``` in [Netron](https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron) tool? This tool will give you detail of Input and output of tflite model

Comment: hi Afsaredrisy i did try that for input the tool gives float32[1,1] and output it gives float32[1,1]

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I fixed it configuring sigmoid simplification to the number of tags instead of value=1

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).